# How to calculate the Monthly Average over Multiple Years with multiple Latitude and Longitude - Pandas - Xarray

Tags: python, mean, python-xarray

I have three variables (T2M, U50M, V50M) from which I would like to find the January average, February average, etc over Multiple Years.
I have a xarry.Dataset - name Multidata:

```
Dimensions:  (time: 17520, lat: 17, lon: 15)
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float64 47.0 47.5 48.0 48.5 49.0 ... 53.0 53.5 54.0 54.5 55.0
  * lon      (lon) float64 6.25 6.875 7.5 8.125 8.75 ... 13.12 13.75 14.38 15.0
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2001-01-01T00:30:00 ... 2002-12-31T23:30:00
Data variables:
    T2M      (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(24, 17, 15), meta=np.ndarray>
    V50M     (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(24, 17, 15), meta=np.ndarray>
    U50M     (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(24, 17, 15), meta=np.ndarray>
```

I tried: ---- but only get monthly mean from each year

```
monthly_data = Multidata.resample(time="MS").mean()

output: 

<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (time: 24, lat: 17, lon: 15)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2001-01-01 2001-02-01 ... 2002-12-01
  * lat      (lat) float64 47.0 47.5 48.0 48.5 49.0 ... 53.0 53.5 54.0 54.5 55.0
  * lon      (lon) float64 6.25 6.875 7.5 8.125 8.75 ... 13.12 13.75 14.38 15.0
Data variables:
    T2M      (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 17, 15), meta=np.ndarray>
    V50M     (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 17, 15), meta=np.ndarray>
    U50M     (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 17, 15), meta=np.ndarray>
```

I tried also: but get again only the monthly mean from each year

```
year_month_idx = year_month_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([Multidata['time.year'].values, Multidata['time.month'].values])
Multidata.coords['year_month'] = ('time', year_month_idx)
monthly_data2 = Multidata.groupby('year_month').mean()

output:

<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:             (year_month: 24, lat: 17, lon: 15)
Coordinates:
  * lat                 (lat) float64 47.0 47.5 48.0 48.5 ... 54.0 54.5 55.0
  * lon                 (lon) float64 6.25 6.875 7.5 8.125 ... 13.75 14.38 15.0
  * year_month          (year_month) MultiIndex
  - year_month_level_0  (year_month) int64 2001 2001 2001 ... 2002 2002 2002
  - year_month_level_1  (year_month) int64 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ... 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
Data variables:
    T2M                 (year_month, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 17, 15), meta=np.ndarray>
    V50M                (year_month, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 17, 15), meta=np.ndarray>
    U50M                (year_month, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 17, 15), meta=np.ndarray>
```

Where is my mistake, how can I get the monthly mean overall years together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand, you're after the long-term mean for each month. If so, you can use xarray with `groupby()` instead of `resample()` to calculate these climatologies.

```
climatology = Multidata.groupby("time.month").mean("time")
```

See xarray docs [here](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/examples/weather-data.html) calculating monthly anomalies.